# Managed Metadata Service Connection properties bringin up a "(500) Internal Server Error". Term Store not available

Tags: 2010, managed-metadata

Using SharePoint 2010 we recently decided to start using the Metadata feature. Our term store wasn't working. I found that when we open the Metadata Connector Properties we get the following error:

> Error
> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

I tried creating a new Metadata Service Application and the error persists. The Metadata service is running and I tried running Configuration Wizard \ PSConfig with no change. I checked the application pools and they are all up and running.

I checked the logs and found this error correlated error

> Exception returned from back end service. System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The >content type text/html; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content >type of the binding (application/soap+msbin1). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the >IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly.

We are using Classic Mode Authentication so I have no idea why we are getting this error.

Any fixes or suggestions?

Comment: I have encountered this problem with SharePoint 2013 and a web application that is in classic mode auth. I fear that its unsupported unless the web app is in Claims?